# Does the US IRS tax board have a provision that any mistake or error such as a few cents or a couple of dollars will not be followed?

Tags: united-states, irs, retirement

When I transfer money from my account to another account (such as from Traditional IRA to Roth IRA), the rule is that if the money has appreciated, then I need to pay tax on it.

But the money is in a money market form, so what if the amount appreciated, let's say by one cent or a few cents, and I didn't pay tax on it, is there a provision or rule or rule of thumb that it won't be followed?

Similarly, if there was some transfer of money and let's say, if the limit of IRA and Roth IRA is $6500 per year, but if there was some small mistakes and the amount is $6501.56, then would that be a big concern or cause a revoke of the whole account?

If it is spending 2 hours for a few cents or a $1.56 error, it can be somewhat wasteful for their time and my time, and if it can be ignored, it'd be more beneficial to us, but if they revoke the whole account, that is another matter.

Comment: I don't understand what "some transfer of money" has to do with the contribution limit. The contribution limit applies to your direct contributions, which you have to specify explicitly. The contribution limit has nothing to do with rollovers or conversions between IRAs.

Comment: The $1.56 is not an error. Just declare $6500 contributed and $6502 converted. The $2 will be taxable but there's a good chance it won't even affect your total tax. There is no limit on how much you can convert in a year.

Comment: 'transferring' _from traditional to Roth_ is a _conversion_, and the amount converted is taxed _except_ if you had _nondeductible_ contributions (called 'basis') in the traditional. That's how the so-called backdoor Roth works, as long as you don't already have a trad IRA: when you are over the AGI limit to contribute to Roth, you make a nondeductible contribution to a trad, which has no AGI limit, then _convert_ to Roth, also with no AGI limit; in this case the basis is not taxed and only earnings/gains are; is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 according to Fidelity or Charles Schwab, it is taxed if there is any gain when the money sits in the Traditional IRA and then converted to Roth. As I said, if due to the cash being in money market, there is a one cent or a few cents of appreciation (due to interest or fluctuation), then supposedly it needs to be taxed on that few cents

Comment: _For backdoor_ that's correct (and consistent with what I said) because you make nondeductible contributions and that is not taxed on conversion but gain is. For most trad IRAs it's not correct because most contributions are deductible and therefore both contributions and gains are taxed on conversion (or other distribution). Your Q does not say which and it makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

The IRS wants taxpayers to round the numbers on their tax forms. Therefore it is possible that a change of less than $1.00 may not cause any other numbers on the form to change.

In addition the tax tables have $50 buckets so it is possible that the total taxable income can move by tens of dollars without changing the amount of tax. But if the taxable income goes past the highest number in the tax table, and the software uses the formula, the delta that will cause a change in tax will be smaller

When it comes to contribution limits, expect that the software will catch the overage and apply the appropriate penalties. I would expect that the consumer and professional tax software will catch these issues also.

Contributing too much to an IRA, 401(k), or HSA doesn't invalidate the account, but the IRS does require the overage to be addressed by either withdrawing the excess and/or paying a fine. Check the deadlines for addressing the specific overage.

It is possible that the IRS will automatically address the issue, and generate a bill for you. But in other cases it is best for the taxpayer to address the issue directly to limit the interest and penalties.

Answer (score 1):

The IRS allows rounding to whole dollars as long as you do it uniformly on all of your schedules and forms. See the [instructions to the form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#en_US_2022_publink24811vd0e4579):

> You can round off cents to whole dollars on your return and schedules. If you do round to whole dollars, you must round all amounts. To round, drop amounts under 50 cents and increase amounts from 50 to 99 cents to the next dollar. For example, $1.39 becomes $1 and $2.50 becomes $3.
>
> If you have to add two or more amounts to figure the amount to enter on a line, include cents when adding the amounts and round off only the total.
>
> If you are entering amounts that include cents, make sure to include the decimal point. There is no cents column on the form.

Generally the IRS would give you an opportunity to correct mistakes before taking drastic actions. If you're sent a notice about a change to your return, adjustment, or correction - read it carefully. Sometimes (especially for minor math errors) they'll just propose the change and you silently agree to it by not responding. For more significant changes, like recharacterization of types of income or requirement to withdraw excess contribution to a retirement account, you may need to take some action or pay additional taxes (like in your IRA example - you'd need to withdraw the excess and/or pay a 6% excise tax).

*Knowingly* submitting an incorrect return is a criminal fraud, so if all the information is known to you and you intentionally report wrong amounts - you may get into trouble (see [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155660/can-a-single-file-tax-as-married-file-jointly-to-take-advantage-of-more-standa/155663#155663) for details). If your expectation is that the government will be "cost-effective" in this then check the statute quotes: if convicted, you'll pay all the prosecution costs, so even if the fraud is for $1.56, it will be worth the government time to prosecute if they're confident in their ability to secure a conviction and your ability to pay the associated fines and costs.